# How do i pass data from main activity to my database in android

Tags: android

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

}
```

Database.java

```
public void insertSettings(String lattitude, String longitude)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LATTITUDE, lattitude);
    values.put(LONGITUDE, longitude);
    db.insertOrThrow(LOCATE_TABLE, null, values); 
}
```

I need to pass string lat and string lng to database... I am new..so pardon my mistakes and please help.

Comment: Like getting an instance of `Database` and calling the method `insertSettings` on it ? ...

Comment: yourDatabaseReference.insertSettings(lat, lng)  where yourDatabaseReference is an instance of Database.java ?

Comment: i want to call the method  insertSettings and get the values stored in my database @Michael Laffargue

Comment: @Archit Obviously `insertSettings` will `set` value not `get` there has to be another method. Just read the doc given 2Dee

Comment: Thank u all...my work done